# How to get IntelliJ to use more than one thread for background work?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, metrics, intellij-plugin

Using the [MetricsReloaded](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/93-metricsreloaded) plugin it is possible to have IntelliJ compute various code metrics values; either for single files, packages, ... or the whole project.

When I do that on our really large project it would probably take *ages* to have the operation finish. It *seems* to me that IntelliJ is only using a single thread/process that computes the metric sequentially. One file after the other.

Now I am simply wondering if there are ways to *speed up* this process, like allowing IntelliJ to use like *more than one* thread.

Comment: Parallel processing must be implemented inside the specific plug-in by the plug-in developer. IntelliJ IDEA can't do that automatically for all the possible cases for the obvious reasons. IDE indexing and compilation can utilize multiple threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parallel processing must be implemented inside the specific plug-in by the plug-in developer. IntelliJ IDEA can't do that automatically for all the possible cases for the obvious reasons. IDE indexing and compilation can utilize multiple threads.